# Account List View - Insufficient Privileges Error

Tags: list-view

User has a permission set that provides "View All" on account and contact.
User can access individual records however when they try to access any list view, it throws this error.

"Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors."

We've done the same setup for other custom objects and the user can view their list views just fine. This issue is only on Account and Contact objects.

What are we missing?

Permission set assigned to user: View all and has Read access to all fields
[image: Permission set assigned to user]

Account list view configuration: No filters and is set to view all
[image: account list view configuration]

Logged in as user: Can access account /001
[image: logged in as user - can access /001]

Logged in as user: Can access account records
[image: Logged in as user: Can access account records]

Logged in as user: Cannot access any list view
[image: logged in as user - cannot access account list view]

Comment: Can you check this setting on list view, Who sees this list view? (All users can see this list view, Share list view with groups of users, Only I can see this list view)

Comment: @Vinay All users can see the list

Comment: Is it any list view at all, or is it a specific list view? If it is a specific list view or views, what filtering has been set up?

Comment: Also check the permissions on any Custom fields that might be added recently and are used in the object view

Comment: Do you see this issue in classic, lightning or both? [KI](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwGOAA0/queue-list-view-inconsistency-between-classic-and-lightning). Can you pls include list view screenshot

Comment: @Vinay we're only on classic

Comment: @CallumMacErlich we have a list view which displays all account, no filtering, and all can view. this still fails

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов may i know why that matters? we don't let this user view all fields, but they can view all records.

Comment: @sforce can you check in lightning?

Comment: I would recommend to share some screenshots of those list view sharing and list all fields included in this list view, so we could easier identify the possible root cause.

Comment: @Vinay user cannot have access to lightning

Comment: @WayneNi done adding photos

Comment: @sforce thanks for that, I did noticed one thing, what is the permission of Account/Contact records for user? they may have access to particular one record, but it didn't mean they have access all records, if you grant them view all records permission, does error still exist?

Comment: @WayneNi Yes, we've assigned them a permission set which has View All permission to both Account and Contact and error still exists. The first screenshot is the permission set which has View All permission to Account.

Comment: Might be worth checking [field level security](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_fls.htm&type=5) set on the object directly for the fields used in the view, since this overrules permissions set on profile/permissionset. I've had issues where one of the fields was inaccessible to the user and the listview was no longer functional (this was on lightning though)